# Can pandas duplicate data and merge with another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have df1 with only one row. 
df2 have multiple rows(we say 8 rows)

I used concat function to join these. 
Concat function put df1 at 0 index and df2 starts at index1 on right side of df1.

Can pandas repeat df1 as much as the df2 and starts both at index 0

Comment: You need a merge or join for that.

Comment: both df have different columns/headers. I need them side by side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea is create same index in both values by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with method='ffill' for repeat values and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), also [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) is used if different first index values for correct match:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':['s'],
         'B':[50],
         'C':[70]
})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'D':list('abcdef'),
         'E':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'F':[7,8,9,4,2,3],

}, index = [10,11,12,13,14,15])

df1 = df1.set_index(df2.index[:len(df1)]).reindex(df2.index, method='ffill')
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
print (df)
    A   B   C  D  E  F
10  s  50  70  a  4  7
11  s  50  70  b  5  8
12  s  50  70  c  4  9
13  s  50  70  d  5  4
14  s  50  70  e  5  2
15  s  50  70  f  4  3
```

Or if first index values are same in both DataFrames:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':['s'],
         'B':[50],
         'C':[70]
})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'D':list('abcdef'),
         'E':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'F':[7,8,9,4,2,3],

})

df1 = df1.reindex(df2.index, method='ffill')
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
print (df)
   A   B   C  D  E  F
0  s  50  70  a  4  7
1  s  50  70  b  5  8
2  s  50  70  c  4  9
3  s  50  70  d  5  4
4  s  50  70  e  5  2
5  s  50  70  f  4  3
```

Comment: Can you please explain this? I am new to pandas

Comment: ```Length mismatch: Expected 26 rows, received array of length 25```
The error I received.

Comment: ```df1 = df1.set_index(df2.index[:len(df2)]).reindex(df2.index, method='ffill')```

Comment: @HusnainIqbal - there is typo `df1 = df1.set_index(df2.index[:len(df1)]).reindex(df2.index, method='ffill')` instead `df1 = df1.set_index(df2.index[:len(df2)]).reindex(df2.index, method='ffill')`

Comment: Nopes. It makes the df1 blank. The second one

Comment: @HusnainIqbal - For me working correct, edited answer with sample data

Comment: Why you have used lambda

Comment: @HusnainIqbal - It is only for sample data, it is not used with real data

Comment: Thank you so much. I was doing it step by step. When done at once, it did the job.

Answer (score 0):

As I proposed in a comment, `.join()` (or `.merge()`) is a perfect tool for this operation:

```
# A one-row DataFrame
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5]], columns=list("abcde"))

# A multirow DataFrame
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]], columns=("f",))

# A combination
df1.join(df2, how='outer').ffill()
#     a    b    c    d    e  f
# 0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  1
# 1  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  2
# 2  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  3
# 3  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  4
# 4  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  5
```

You can convert the floating-point numbers back to integers, if needed.